# Align TextView and EditText left in vertically oriented LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I am using a `LinearLayout` as view group which holds two children (`TextView` and `EditText`). My XML code looks as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Edit Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

which will produce the following design:

[image]

As depicted in the zoomed-in view on the left, `TextView`and `EditText` are not equally aligned vertically (`EditText` is indented a bit more as shown by the small red arrows).

It seems there is a bit of a padding (a few `dp`) around the hint and the line underneath which prevents them from "touching" the left edge of their view field. Is there any way to force the hint within `EditText` to squeeze to the left of its view field?

How can I get rid of this indentation, **other than by adding paddings and margins**?

Thanks for any ideas and advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without add any paddings and margins you can use a custom drawable for the background of your `Edittext` to remove the default padding

in drawable/edittext_bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now use it in your editext:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:hint="Edit Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should not be in this way... You should check your style.xml, maybe you set additional margins there.

Also, try to specify layout_gravity:"left" attribute.

Comment: layout_gravity doesnt change the position of the hint within the `EditText`, it changes the position of the `EditText` as a whole

Answer (score 0):

try typing letters on Edit Text   then you can see both textview and edit text was aligned equally

Comment: No it is not aligned equally when entering something on the `EditText`...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)? It's removing the need to have so much hierarchy in xml layouts and is easy to use.

Comment: It is the same using `ConstraintLayout` as the problem is not the view group but the `EditText` itself, i.e. the padding around the hint.

Comment: Then make a custom EditText yourself, remove left padding/margin of the hint and the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

this preview, run the simulator for correct preview. 
But, for best result use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Comment: I have ran it both on a real device and on an emulator and the indentation is still there...

Comment: it is possible to try TextInputLayout is specific for this cases